# Force the browser to send some HTTP request header

Tags: gwt, http-headers, webbrowser-control, http-status-code-401

I need to include some secure (BASIC authentication) application.

when I open the application URL in the browser, the browser asks me to enter your credentials ...

> **what I know is that:**
>
> 1. The browser ask the server to get
>      some URL -- the url of the app
> 2. The server checks the request header
>      for the `Authentication header` and
>      didn't find it
> 3. The server sends `401` to the
>      browser back
> 4. The browser interpret this response
>      code into a message dialog that
>      shows to me asking me to enter the
>      username/password to send back to
>      the server in the `Authentication`
>      request header

So far... so good, I can write some page (in JSP) that send this required http request header to the request that is calling this page..
So I'll call this application through my page..

The problem here is, this application (in fact a GWT application) contains a reference to some Javascript and CSS files that is coming from the server that hosts this application. the application page that I import looks like:

```
<html>
    <link href="http://application_host/cssfile.css" />
    <link href="http://application_host/javascriptfile.js" />
    .....
</html>
```

So, again I found the application asks me for the authentication crenditals for the css and js files!

I am thinking of many solutions but don't know the applicability of each

- One solution is to ask the browser
  (via Javascript) to send the request
  header (`Authentication`) when he
  asks the server for the js and css
  files

please give me your opinions about that... and any other suggestions will be very welcomed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're running into some weirdness with how your server is configured. Authentication happens in context of a *authentication realm*. Your assets should either be in the same authentication realm as your page, or (more likely) should not require authentication at all. The browser should be caching credentials for the given realm, and not prompt for them again.

See the protocol example on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your story, something tells me your problem is with the authentication method itsef. Not how to implement it. Why do you want to bother with the request header so much?

As far as i know, you can configure your container (ie Tomcat) to force http authentication for certain urls. Your container will make sure that authentication has taken place. No need to set http headers yourself whatsoever.

Perhaps you can explain a bit better what you are trying to achieve, instead of telling implementation details?

Comment: Well, although as you guess, I am the application developer, but I am not the person who put the security roles.. it is the appliction deployer and he put the authentication on all the application urls (/*).

Answer (score 0):

Why css & js files are kept in protected area of server? You need to place files into public area of your server. If you don't have public area, so you nead to prpvide for it. how to do it depends from serverside software architecture & configuration.